# Difference between %f and %F (it's not that obvious!)

Tags: vimrc, statusline

This might be a silly question, but what is the **actual** difference between `%f` and `%F` in status line?

From `:h statusline`:

> - `f` Path to the file in the buffer, as typed or relative to current directory.
> - `F` Full path to the file in the buffer.

However, as long as I don't use the menu and use `:e ...` instead, I don't see any difference.

```
set laststatus=2
set statusline=%f\ \ %F
```

- `:e c:\users\john\desktop\test1.txt` → `~\Desktop\test1.txt`
- `:e c:\foo\bar\test2.txt` → `c:\foo\bar\test2.txt`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The key is "as typed". Let's do a test using your supplied status line config: `set statusline=%f\ \ %F`

**Setup**<sup>*</sup>

1. `mkdir -p /tmp/foo` : create a directory in a scratch area
2. `cd /tmp/foo` : navigate to this new directory
3. `touch a b` : create two empty files, "a" and "b"
4. `vim` : start Vim with no arguments
5. (in Vim) `:e /tmp/foo/a` then `:e ./b`

**Result**

When viewing file "a" the status line shows

```
/tmp/foo/a  /tmp/foo/a
```

When viewing file "b" it shows

```
./b  /tmp/foo/b
```

In both cases the first item, for `%f`, is the exact file path we passed to the `:e` command and the second item, for `%F`, is the file's full path regardless of what we typed.

* <sub>Though you appear to be on Windows, I know almost nothing about cmd.exe or Powershell commands so I'm using shell commands. If you want to recreate this yourself I imagine it'll be relatively easy to translate to Win equivalents.</sub>